# Pygame Window refuses to start after importing * from pygame.local

Tags: python, pygame

So I started programming a game for a school project and currently face a problem with `event.type` `KEYDOWN`.
This is my Code. When running it a window opens but it stays completely black without showing either the background color or the sprite. I tried pinpointing the issue with the print() commands to see in what line exactly the code stops working. Every, except the last print command is executed, which leaves me to believe the While Loop is the cause of my problem.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
print("Import complete")

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
TITLE = "Tales of Tesbold"
print("Window complete")

Tesbold = Actor("tesbold.png")   #Sprites vordefinition
Tesbold.x = 200
Tesbold.y = 100
print("Tesbold complete")
wechsel = True
def draw():                 #Hintergrund und alle Sprites
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill((200,200,200))
    Tesbold.draw()
    
print("Draw Screen complete")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == quit:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if(event.key == K_RIGHT):
                Tesbold.x += 10
print("While Loop complete")
```

This is the console output:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Import complete
Window complete
Tesbold complete
Draw Screen complete


---------- FINISHED ----------
exit code: 2 status: 0
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong for it to not function anymore?

Comment: When you do `sys.exit()`, it exits the execution of the program right then and there. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: And, you never called the draw function, thus nothing got displayed on the screen.

Comment: Python is case sensitive: `quit` -> `QUIT`

Comment: @101donutman in a different code that I build around on_mouse_down() I didn't have to call the draw function as it worked anyway. Should I add a draw() to the code?

Comment: Yes, and add it at the beginning of the code thats within the while - true codeblock, as that way it gets called every iteration.

Comment: @101donutman when adding "draw()" to the code in any way I get following error: NameError: name 'screen' is not defined. Interestingly it seems to be a problem with the while loop. Like I said I have a different code with a different approach but as the internet has a lot more threads about events than on_key_down() I wanted to switch to that. In the different approach I don't even need "draw()" and it still displays both the background aswell as the sprite. I am currently confused as to what python actually wants from me.

Comment: You try to mix [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) and [pygame zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). These are different libraries

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive. The event type enumerators are all written in capital letters. See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module:

<s>`if event.type == quit:`</s>

```py
if event.type == QUIT:
```

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function and uninitialize all pygame modules.

Comment: This doesnt seem the problem. When I cut it out using an "#" it gives me the same result.

Comment: @Ignitris Of course it is a problem. Anyway, what is `Actor`? Do you mix [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) and [pygame zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: I mean apparently. I looked up a pygame tutorial and Actor was described as the movable figure. The "actor" of the game.

Comment: @Ignitris But not in Pygame. [Actor](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#actors) is an object of Pygame Zero. [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) != [Pygme Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html)

Comment: What would you recommend? Pygame or Pygame Zero?

Comment: @Ignitris This question is opinion based. If you are a complete beginner then use Pygame Zero. If you have little experience (around 1 month), use Pygame. After a while, you won't be using any of them. Both are for learning purposes only.